# how to install STS to eclipse oxygen(2018.march) sts is not available in the market place?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-oxygen

how to install STS to eclipse oxygen(2018.march) sts is not available in the market place ? i have tried it manually using help> install software> unzipped folder > but it is not working

Comment: "not working" do you have any error?

Comment: it's saying like could not find file . when i give the filepath

Comment: Why to install over an existing Eclipse if you can download the Eclipse STS based. Please check: https://spring.io/tools

Comment: @ChristianEduardoGaldamez May be OP have already have an eclipse with other plugins already configured.

Comment: You are living in the 2018 just for your plugins? Come on man, all those plugins can be installed into STS Eclipse based IDE too, think, what would be easier? to install the entire STS to Oxigen or pass to the new tools of STS Eclipse based IDE and install the plugins there?

Comment: am using older version of oxygen. sts is not available in the eclipse market place for my version:(

Comment: Are you talking about STS 3 or 4? What is the reason to use such an old Eclipse version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are interested in the Spring Tools 4, there is no version available that is compatible with Eclipse Oxygen (4.7).

In case you are interested in the Spring Tool Suite 3, there is an update site URL that you could use to manually install that into Eclipse Oxygen from here:

https://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.7

This points to version 3.9.5, which is the newest version that is compatible with Eclipse Oxygen (4.7). **But this version is outdated and no longer maintained, so we do not recommend to install and use that anymore!**

I strongly recommend to use the latest of Spring Tools 4 on Eclipse 2019-12, which you can download from https://spring.io/tools instead.